# Optimize query with COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, database-performance

I got table with 145821312 rows :/

```
CREATE TABLE core.conversations
(
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  user_to_id integer NOT NULL,
  last_message_timestamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  body text NOT NULL,
  status core.message_status DEFAULT 'unread'::core.message_status,
  my_message boolean NOT NULL,
  delete_message_timestamp timestamp with time zone,
  deleted boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT userid_usertiid UNIQUE (, )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I got query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM core.conversations WHERE user_id=xxxx AND status='unread' AND deleted='false';
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE shows:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=930.17..930.18 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.027..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Only Scan using useridunreaddeleted_idx on conversations  (cost=0.57..929.59 rows=229 width=0) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ((user_id = 123123) AND (status = 'unread'::core.message_status) AND (deleted = false))"
"        Filter: (NOT deleted)"
"        Heap Fetches: 0"
"Planning time: 0.239 ms"
"Execution time: 0.130 ms"
```

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX useridunreaddeleted_idx
  ON core.conversations
  USING btree
  (user_id, status, deleted);
```

Is there any way to optimize this query? Some other index type? Its very simple query, but i know there is a lot of data in table ;/ Or should i make some agregates to get this counter...

EDIT:i changed query, it was wrong, with no count(*), sorry

Comment: *"Execution time: 0.066 ms"* Your query took less than a second and you want to make it faster o.0?

Comment: Its cached now... this query in production takes about 5-15 seconds. And there are more 'heavy' users, that have more unread messages...

Comment: 5-15 seconds might be the best you'll get. That said, you could try a partial index, say something like `CREATE INDEX ON core.conversations (user_id) WHERE status = 'unread'::core.message_status AND NOT deleted`. That should, if nothing else, reduce your index size.

Comment: I would swap `status` and `deleted` columns in the index (or even have `status` first to have the nonnulls and the higher selectivity first. Of course only of status is actually well distributed.

Comment: If your concern is the performance of a query on production, it would make sense to supply that execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to look at `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output for the query on the production system.

From the database angle you probably cannot do any better than you are doing with that index, and I'd say that to improve the performance, you'll have to improve the hardware:

- Lots of RAM – at least the index, but ideally the whole table should be cached.
- Fast I/O subsystem.

Comment: We got 3 instance - like xlarge amazon ec2. One master and two slaves. and HDD NOT SSD ;/

Comment: Well, maybe that's your problem.

Comment: I checked, each have 8 CPU and 16G of RAM.

Comment: 8 CPUs is not going to help you without parallel query

Answer (score 0):

What about partition? Will it help?

```
CREATE TABLE core.conversations_0
(
  CONSTRAINT conversations_0_user_id_check CHECK ((user_id % 1000) = 0)
) INHERITS (core.conversations);
...
CREATE TABLE core.conversations_1000
(    
  CONSTRAINT conversations_1000_user_id_check CHECK ((user_id % 1000) = 999)
) INHERITS (core.conversations);
```

And indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX conversations_0_user_id_idx
  ON core.conversations_0
  USING btree
  (user_id)
  WHERE status = 'unread'::core.message_status AND NOT deleted;
...
CREATE INDEX conversations_1000_user_id_idx
  ON core.conversations_1000
  USING btree
  (user_id)
  WHERE status = 'unread'::core.message_status AND NOT deleted;
```

But still, i dont know why this query scan all indexes?

```
SET constraint_exclusion = on;
EXPLAIN  ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM core.conversations WHERE user_id=12728967 AND status='unread' AND deleted='false';

 "Aggregate  (cost=89.77..89.78 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Append  (cost=0.28..89.75 rows=11 width=0) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_user_id_idx on conversations  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_0_user_id_idx on conversations_0  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_1_user_id_idx on conversations_1  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_2_user_id_idx on conversations_2  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_3_user_id_idx on conversations_3  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_4_user_id_idx on conversations_4  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_5_user_id_idx on conversations_5  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_6_user_id_idx on conversations_6  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_7_user_id_idx on conversations_7  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_8_user_id_idx on conversations_8  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_9_user_id_idx on conversations_9  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"Planning time: 1.229 ms"
"Execution time: 0.133 ms"
```

EDIT:

Adding this to query 'user_id%10 = 7'

```
SET constraint_exclusion = on;
EXPLAIN  ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM core.conversations WHERE user_id=12728967 AND user_id%10 = 7 AND status='unread' AND deleted='false';

"Aggregate  (cost=16.46..16.47 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Append  (cost=0.28..16.45 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_user_id_idx on conversations  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"              Filter: ((user_id % 10) = 7)"
"        ->  Index Scan using conversations_7_user_id_idx on conversations_7  (cost=0.12..8.15 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (user_id = 12728967)"
"              Filter: ((user_id % 10) = 7)"
"Planning time: 0.950 ms"
"Execution time: 0.070 ms"
```

But it scans also 'mother' table big index ;/